# if(isset($submit)) не работает

Tags: php

Делаю страницу регистрации в PHPStorm, соединение с БД ок, но нажатие на кнопку просто обновляет страницу, не выдавая никаких сообщений. 
Переменная в isset с name кнопки в html совпадают.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" align="center">
    New User?<br>
    Login <input name="login" type="text"/><br>
    Password <input name="password" type="password"/><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
// Страница регистрации нового пользователя

# Соединямся с БД
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql!");
mysqli_select_db($link,"yii") or die ("no database!");

$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if(isset($submit))
{
    $err = array();
    print 'good';

    if (empty($_POST['login']))
    {
        $err[] = "Введите логин";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $err[] = "Введите пароль";
    }

    # проверям логин
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",$_POST['login']))
    {
        $err[] = "Логин может состоять только из букв английского алфавита и цифр";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['login']) < 4 or strlen($_POST['login']) > 15)
    {
        $err[] = "Логин должен быть не меньше 4-х символов и не больше 15";
    }

    # проверяем, не сущестует ли пользователя с таким именем
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['login'])."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        $err[] = "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует";
    }

    # Если нет ошибок, то добавляем в БД нового пользователя
    if(count($err) == 0)
    {

        $login = $_POST['login'];

        # Убераем лишние пробелы и делаем шифрование
        $password = md5(trim($_POST['password']));

        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO user SET username='".$login."', auth_key='".$password."'");
        //header("Location: auth.php"); exit();
    }
    else
    {
        print "<b>При регистрации произошли следующие ошибки:</b><br>";
        foreach($err AS $error)
        {
            print $error."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Зачем гадать? Ну вставьте перед `$submit = $_POST['submit'];` `var_dump($_POST)` и посмотрите, что у Вас приходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А сделайте вместо

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if(isset($submit))
```

такое условие

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

форма-то у вас одна, думаю, на этом файле висит.

Comment: Нажатие теперь работает, но при любом вводе логина и пароля все ошибки выводятся на экран

Comment: @Maxkb24, `var_dump($_POST);` вам уже предлагали добавить, чтобы увидеть, что пришло из браузера. Покажите результат при логине/пароле = test/root, например.